# Separate sub-sites into their own application pools?

Tags: user-profile-service, upgrade, application-pool

I'm in the middle of an upgrade of a SharePoint 2007 farm.  In this old farm, they have My Sites set up to share a database and application pool with everything else in the farm.  As we move ahead with the upgrade to SharePoint 2010, I'm recommending that they move My Sites to their own dedicated web application and own app pool because according to best practices, I'm under the impression this is the best way to run My Sites.  However, they don't want the URL for their My Sites to change from sharepoint.domain.com/mysites.  They seem to think that you can run multiple application pools under one web application.  I know it can work the other way around (you can run multiple web applications under one app pool), but I am not aware of it working the way they describe.  Even though I'm experienced with SharePoint, I'm no guru, so I want to make sure I'm not missing something.  Is there a way to separate the My Sites from their main content and still keep the URL the same?